# Ecto Errors Part of Happy Path

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

*Elixir and Phoenix outsider here*
I'm attempting to learn some of the best practices of using what has so far been a really excellent language and framework.

One thing I have noted in the community (and agree with) is that exceptions should be "exceptional." They should not be used to control the flow of an application. Therefore, try/raise should not be used as part of the "happy path" of the application.

This seems to be contrary to the generators that phoenix provides out of the box.

**Example**

```
# Code genereated by elixir
def get_admin_user!(id), do: Repo.get!(AdminUser, id)
```

The code above was generated by Phoenix and will throw an exception if the user is not found. It appears this is the intended way to query Ecto because this code was produced using `mix phx.gen.context`

**Question**: Why is it that `Ecto` and `Phoenix` uses exceptions to report on regular errors? If this is correct, what is the appropriate way to handle these errors without adding try/raise blocks to every action?

Comment: you don't handle such errors, you want error as data, create a new function without bang

Comment: So, all "happy path" exceptions generated by Ecto are handled by `Plug.Exception`?

Comment: Yes, this is done through the [`phoenix_ecto`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto) library, which [implements](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/blob/master/lib/phoenix_ecto/plug.ex) the `Plug.Exception` protocol for relevant errors. As far as I understand, these are not meant to be used with try/rescue though, the error handling is done through this protocol. When you need to handle the case yourself, you should use `Repo.get/2` instead as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer to the first question as to why Ecto is designed to report errors in cases that appear to be part of the "Happy Path."

The idiomatic approach to handling these exceptions, is to let Phoenix do it for you using [Plug.Exception](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Exception.html). You can also extend these exceptions for mapping other general errors to response codes and responses.